# Running multiple loops whilst still listening to key inputs

Tags: python, loops, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am working on a game driver but I can't get multiple loops to work together, I've tried using Threading and Multiprocessing but nothing seems to be working.

```py
import turtle
from time import sleep
from functools import partial
game_active = True
render_speed = 0.01
driver_speed = 0.1


def prep_assets():
    print('asset WIP')


def game_render():
    while game_active:
        print('render WIP')
        sleep(render_speed)


def game_driver():
    while game_active:
        print('driver WIP')
        sleep(driver_speed)


def update_data(key):
    print(f'{key} wip')


prep_assets()
game_driver()
game_render()
turtle.onkey(partial(update_data, 'w'), 'w')
turtle.onkey(partial(update_data, 'a'), 'a')
turtle.onkey(partial(update_data, 's'), 's')
turtle.onkey(partial(update_data, 'd'), 'd')
turtle.onkey(partial(update_data, 'q'), 'q')
turtle.onkey(partial(update_data, 'e'), 'e')
turtle.listen()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: "I've tried using Threading and Multiprocessing " We can only help with code that is actually shown to us. This version of the code doesn't appear to contain any such attempt.

Comment: Are you sure you need multiple loops? If you explain what problem you're [really trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) there's probably a better solution. Bring in threading is almost certainly an antipattern for a simple turtle app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can u explain why Threading and Multiprocessing but nothing seems to be working.

```
 Thread(target = game_render).start()
    Thread(target = game_driver).start()
```